# How to make webpage show in search results

Tags: search

Our company website transitioned to be hosted by google two months ago. It used to be at the top of the search results but now is not listed at all. 
initially there was some problems with the website not showing at all when you type in the address which have been resolved.
Search results show links on other websites to our page.

I apologise i have no tech knowledge. I am not sure where to begin to trouble shoot this problem.

Thank you in advance.
Glenn

Comment: Hi there, this isn't really the correct forum for this question. You might do better to post it on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo

Answer (score 0):

SEO is a complex topic - I would recommend searching for Getting started with SEO and reading some of [articles that come up](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/217483)

Some basics you will need are meta and title tags, adding your site index to Google and a decent amount of original content.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I dont think this is a SEO issue, my hunch is its something in how the website was created that mean its not showing up. 
meta and title tags, adding your site index to Google look like solid leads, i'll get onto those this week.